Which printer to buy to be able to print postcards on paper 350 g/m²
For my hobby (postcrossing), I make designs of postcards and normally get them printed via a professional printer. But for several reasons, I would like to cut out a middle-man. I am not planning to print at the industrial scale, but I send about 2 postcards daily, and I would like to offer the service to my friends-in-hobby. So we can assume for this question that I am looking at printing out 300 postcards each month in one batch.
I found that the quality of cards printed on paper 350 g/m² is better than those printed on something lighter.
All the printers I see a peek at the recommended paper density of 280 g/m² or do not list that characteristic at all.
Another thing to keep in mind is that I am planning to be printing postcards, this means that the paper should not be bent into a circle as it passes through the printer. It doesn't really mean much for the lighter paper, but if it is something thick, it can create tubes rather than postcards.
I recognise that normally paper comes in sizes that would require me to cut the paper after it was printed (most postcards are sized as 102mm×152mm or 105mm×146mm), but sometimes I make squares (100mm×100mm or 150mm×150mm). I have no problem with buying a guillotine, but if somehow there is something that combines double-sided printing with simplified cutting, that would of course be better... although, as I've just said cutting can be done afterwards.
I have never purchased the paper myself for card printing, but when I used printing services I found that Splendorgel White 340 g/m² to produce very good results. Glossy papers can be OK sometimes, but often they are difficult to write on, making them not ideal for postcards. However, I would like to consider that alternative as well, as it is possible to write on them, even if difficult.
Finally regarding my budget. I am in Russia and in rubles I would be willing to spend upwards to 100 thousand rubles, let's say that we can round up a little and get 1000 euro budget. It is possible to go slightly over if the quality makes it necessary, but not if we are talking about adding more zeros.

Hi, welcome to Hardware Recs! What size are these postcards typically? A6? 4x6"?

@JMY1000 Edited to add sizes in millimetres.

Great, thanks. What kind of paper finish are you planning on printing on? Something like the Epson ET-8550 can pring on 300g/m² glossy photo paper, but can only do 90g/m² plain paper. Same story with a Canon Pixma Pro-200: 380g/m² vs 105g/m². Also, what your budget here?

@JMY1000 Thanks for engaging with my question. I have added details on paper and also regarding the budget.
